# Comments on two parts of the equation

Tags: equations

I would like to create 3 well aligned equations with self defined tag numbers (I call them 1, 2 and 3). After that I would like to make 2 comments for the three equations.

The expected result would like the attached picture. I appreciate any help, suggestions and tips.

[image: How can I get this by Latex]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `align` for the basic equation work and `stackengine` for the undertext, since it allows for ignoring the width of the undertext.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
3.0 &= \phantom{2}x + y\\
1.5 &= 2x - y\\
\stackunder[1pt]{0.2\vphantom{y}}{\underbrace{\hspace{4ex}}_%
    {\makebox[4.5ex][r]{\scriptsize $n$ observations}}} 
&= \stackunder[1pt]{\phantom{2}x - y}{\underbrace{\hspace{6ex}}_%
    {\makebox[6.5ex][l]{\scriptsize $u$ unknowns}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using the `clap` and `\underbracket` commands, from `mathtools`, and the `alignat` environment:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
3.0 & = & & x + y \\
1.5 & =2 & & x-y \\
\underbracket[,6pt]{0.2\vphantom{y}}_{\shortstack{$\scriptstyle n $ \\[-0.5ex]\clap{\scriptsize observations\enspace}}} & = &
& \!\underbracket[,6pt]{x-y}_{\shortstack{$\scriptstyle n $ \\[-0.5ex]\clap{\scriptsize\enspace unknowns}}}
\end{alignat}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{align}
3 =& x + y \tag{1}
\\
1.5 =& 2x - y \tag{2}
\\
\underbrace{0.2} =& \underbrace{x - y} \tag{3}
\\
n\text{ observations} \phantom{=}& u\text{ unknowns} \notag
\end{align}
```